# OnPress access data of element

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

Hey I got really stucked to this problem. I couldn't solve how to get data of `TouchableHighlight` as soon as I press it. Data are being assigned from an array.

```
class Request extends Component {

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.Clicked = this.Clicked.bind(this)
}

Clicked = () => {
    //console.log(WhatIneed);
};

GetIt = () => {
    return this.state.ArrData.map((MyData) => (
       <View>
          <TouchableHighlight WhatIneed={MyData.ArrVal} onPress={() => {
              this.Clicked();
              }}>
             <Text>Button</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
      ))
   };
}
```

Comment: It's a passed prop, grab it!

Comment: @SterlingArcher Well I tried it. Unfortunately WebStorm says `unresolved var WhatIneed` and log is `undefined`. :(

Comment: try `onPress={() => {
    this.Clicked(MyData.ArrVal);
}}>`
 them 
`Clicked = (WhatIneed) => {
    console.log(WhatIneed);
}`